# Value-at-Risk of two dependent lognormal random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, st.statistics

Hello, (I searched the wohole literature and internet and I have no idea myself for this important question)

Let $(X_1,X_2)$ be a multivariate normal random vector ($X_1$ and $X_2$ need not be independent). Is it possible to calculate
$$VaR_{\alpha}\bigl(e^{X_1}+e^{X_2}\bigr)$$ analyticaly? Or is it even possible to calulate it in terms of  $$VaR_{\alpha}(e^{X_1}) \ \text{ and} \ VaR_{\alpha}(e^{X_2}),$$ i.e. is there a representation (a function $g(\cdot,\cdot)$) of the form
$$VaR_{\alpha}(e^{X_1}+e^{X_2})=g\Bigl(VaR_{\alpha}\bigl(e^{X_1}\bigr),VaR_{\alpha}\bigl(e^{X_2}\bigr)\Bigr)$$.

I would be very thakful for hints.

Comment: Can you solve the problem if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent?

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ were independent then the distribution function of the sum $e^{X_1}+e^{X_2}$ is a convolution. But this way of trying it has the disadvantage that you dont see if it is analyticaly tractable.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on a sister site devoted to quantitative finance:  http://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I was not aware of this page.

Comment: Some useful references are given in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30619/sum-of-log-normal-random-variables (see the accepted answer; you are not going to find something better than approximations).